# check phone settings for haptic feedback

Tags: android, settings, vibration

Is there a way to check if the user has haptic feedback enabled or disabled in their android phone settings? While I think haptic feedback would be useful to my app, I also understand that some people (myself included) generally prefer to have haptic feedback turned off.  The closest thing I can find is 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED
but I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for or how to test against it.

thank you in advance for whatever help you can provide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to resolve it.  here is the code I used:

```
mContentResolver = this.getContentResolver();

int val = Settings.System.getInt(mContentResolver,
                 Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED, 0);
mSettingEnabled = val != 0;
```

Comment: [Settings.System.getInt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#getInt(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String)) should be called in static way.