# Android test if haptic feedback is available

Tags: android

I have seen this question : [check phone settings for haptic feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569398/check-phone-settings-for-haptic-feedback) but I don't understand the solution (for me it does not work).

Is there another solution ? I did not find anything on the javadoc.. ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add this method to any of your classes and use it to check whether haptic feedback is enabled.

```
public static boolean isHapticFeedbackEnabled(Context context) {
    int enabled = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
        android.provider.Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED, 0);
    return enabled != 0;
}
```

The method goes into system settings database and checks value of "haptic_feedback_enabled" setting. If there is 0 then haptic feedback is disables, otherwise it is enabled.

Comment: Getting cannot resolve symbol `Settings` with above code.

Comment: Nvm.  Make sure to import `android.provider.Settings`.

Comment: It returns true for device that doesn't know how to haptic.. Any other ideas?